# Python Encapsulation: overwriting variables with-in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, encapsulation, shallow-copy

**Background:**

- I am using python 2.7.4
- I am reading a document line by line into the class
- I want to have two variables within a class
- One variable(I made it an array called lines) I want to have all the original formatting of the document
- The other variable(I also made into an array called linesfixed), I want to get rid of indentation and line wrap characters "-"

**The Issue:**

My setLinesFixed() method is for some reason modifying both my *lines*(not desired) and *linesfixed*(desired) variables... I am not sure what the problem is, but I feel like it is some sort of encapsulation issue.

**Code in class:**

```
def __init__(self):
    self.lines = []  # sets up the empty array for lines without modifications
    self.linesfixed = []  #sets up the empty array for lines with indentation and line wraps gone

def setLines(self,realfilename):
    tempfile = open(realfilename)
    self.lines = tempfile.readlines() # this sets the self.lines correctly
    tempfile.close()
    # print self.lines gives the desired output >> ["blah blah.. -","blah blah"]

def setLinesFixed(self,templines):
    self.linesfixed = templines 
    index = len(self.linesfixed)-1
    while index >= 0:
        cleanline = self.linesfixed[index].strip()
        if(cleanline == ""):
            self.linesfixed.pop(index)
        elif((cleanline[-1] == "-")and(cleanline[0] != ";")):
            cleanline = cleanline[:-1]
            temp = self.linesfixed.pop(index+1)
            temp = temp.strip()
            self.linesfixed[index] = cleanline + temp
        else:
            self.linesfixed[index] = self.linesfixed[index].strip()
        index = index - 1
    # print self.linesfixed gives me the desired output for fixing lines >> ["blah blah.. blah blah"]
    # print self.lines gives me the same result as self.lines fixed >> ["blah blah.. blah blah"]
```

**Example Input:**

```
self.setLines(["blah blah.. -","blah blah"])
self.setLinesFixed(self.lines)
```

**Actual Output:**

```
self.lines = ["blah blah.. blah blah"]
self.linesfixed = ["blah blah.. blah blah"]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
self.lines = ["blah blah.. -","blah blah"]
self.linesfixed = ["blah blah.. blah blah"]
```

What is wrong here? and why does self.lines get modified as well as self.linesfixed? Is this an encapsulation issue?

Comment: This part of your code is indented incorrectly: `def setLinesFixed(self,templines): ... self.linesfixed = templines`. This is a SyntaxError if you try to run in Python. Please make sure that you copy-paste the correct code.

Comment: You need to pass a shallow copy of the list: `self.setLinesFixed(self.lines[:])`. And I also wonder how your `open()` function is working fine with a list.

Comment: @pts Sorry about that.. The actual code could not be copy and pasted due to its length. So this is the watered down version. Thank you.

Comment: Then use http://pastebin.com/ , or even better: strip it down in a way  that it still works: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not copying the array before modifying it, you're just copying a reference to the array. After this line:

```
self.linesfixed = templines
```

Both `self.linesfixed` and `templines` refer to the same array. To get the intended behavior, you need to clone the array:

```
self.linesfixed = list(templines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a shallow copy, like this:

```
self.linesfixed = list(templines)
```

or this:

```
self.linesfixed = templines[:]
```